# Grep exact match for Kubernetes namespace (non-files)

Tags: bash, kubernetes, azure-aks

Background: I have two deployments in my k8s cluster called (as an example) the following:

```
foo-bar
foo-bar-asd
```

In my pipeline, I want to implement logic which checks if there's any deployments named "foo-bar" already deployed.

How do I construct my command to only fetch/output "foo-bar", and not "foo-bar-asd" ?

I've tried toying around with regex, '^foo-bar$' etc without any success, found through googling/similar stackoverflow-questions.

My current command (which fetches both):

```
kubectl -n my-namespace get deployments | grep foo-bar
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Edit:
Realized beggars can't be choosers, *but* on top of just fetching "foo-bar" I would need the command to not explicitly mention "foo-bar-asd".
(Building a pipeline where this command is to be placed, and is supposed to be generic for different apps. Does not explain fully, but hopefully a little.)

Comment: Use `grep `^foo-bar$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` command can also exclude certain string. You can run something like

`kubectl -n my-namespace get deployments | grep foo-bar | grep -v  foo-bar-asd`

This should show you what you are looking for.

Comment: This worked! Could you see a way to do it without explicitly writing "foo-bar-asd" ?
(Ended up writing 300 characters explaining my situation and why, but it became a mess. I'm basically building a generic pipeline which loads a value depending on the app, e.g. "foo-bar", which is why "foo-bar-asd" would be hard for me as a command in my pipeline)

Comment: If the first deployment will stay as `foo-bar` forever, we don't have to write all the string from beginning to the end. This should also work :

`kubectl -n my-namespace get deployments | grep foo-bar | grep -v  foo-bar-`

I assuming all generated deployments will have a dash (-) after foo-bar. So basically we can separate foo-bar from foo-bar with the dash at the end of it.

Comment: It will - so this is great, and I just verified it worked running it in my pipeline. :) 
Thank you!
Could you edit the result in your post for me to give you the green check?

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

As your search pattern contains hyphens, you can't use "whole words only" as a hyphen is considered a word separator, so my first answer is wrong.
You need to say that your words represent the entire line, which you can do as follows:

```
grep "^foo-bar$"
```

`^` stands for "beginning of line".
`$` stands of "end of line".

**Edit:** first answer, which is wrong.

My version of `grep` (`GNU grep 3.4 ... 2019-12-29`) has a `-w` switch, which I can use for filtering "whole words only", so in your case it would be:

```
grep -w "foo-bar"
```

Comment: Can confirm, your suggestion resulted output containing both deployments. Thanks tho!

Comment: @ErikJönelid: I've adapted my answer, can you check?

Comment: Sorry, does not return anything (strangely) when I try with ^$ beginning/end. I'm also on version 3.4...